# Does anybody facing problem while shutting Ubuntu 11.04 down?

Tags: 11.04

when i clicked on shutdown or enter command halt/halt -f/shutdown; system hangs up. Last log message is "init: rc Main process killed"

Answer (score 2):

I had installed Metasploit on my Ubuntu machine. I simply disable the Metasploit server and ubuntu started to shutting down normally :)